# Not able to compile the JAVA program. I need output when n = 8

Tags: java, loops, output, parseint

It is an algoritm class and i would like to get the output of this program when n = 8

```
import java.io.*;  
public class Algorithm
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int i,j,n;
        String s = in.readLine();
        n = Integer.parseInt(s);
        i = 2;
        while( i<= n)
        {
             for(j=1; j<= n/2; j++)
             System.out.println(i + " "+j)
             System.out.println(i + " " +j);
             i = i+2;
        }
        for (j =0; j<= i ; j+=4)
        System.out.println(" "+j);
    }
}
```

Comment: where did you define `in`

Comment: I wrote the that line twice accidentally, the first println is not suppose to be there. Still the code is not working

Comment: @Amir, I found this is a code given by my professor, and I am trying to find the output, i am not sure either about in

Comment: there is no output. It don't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Algorithm {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        int i, j, n;
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            i = 2;
            while (i <= n) {
                for (j = 1; j <= n / 2; j++) {
                    System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                }
                System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                i = i + 2;
            }
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j += 4) {
                System.out.println(" " + j);
            }
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import java.io.*;  
public class Algorithm
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int i,j,n;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try
        {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String s = in.readLine();
            n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            i = 2;
            while( i<= n)
            {
                 for(j=1; j<= n/2; j++)
                 System.out.println(i + " "+j)
                 System.out.println(i + " " +j);
                 i = i+2;
            }
            for (j =0; j<= i ; j+=4)
             System.out.println(" "+j);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(in != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    in.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. The codes are working fine.